# Mixing Two Textures in Metal Shader

Tags: ios, opengl-es, metal, fragment-shader, metalkit

I have two transparent textures. First one is Source texture, Second one is Mask Texture. I want to mix two textures.

Scenario 1

- source texture having  color and Alpha Mask Texture Having color and Alpha
- Resultant Color and alpha should be multiplied

Scenario 2

- source texture having  color and Alpha Mask Texture alpha is Zero
- Resultant Color and alpha should be Source Texture Color and Alpha

Scenario 3

- source texture having  Alpha zero Mask Texture alpha is having color and alpha
- Resultant Color and alpha should be Zero

How can I achieve this in metal Fragment shader.

```
fragment float4 fragmentShaderone(VertexOut params[[stage_in]],
                                                              texture2d<float, access::sample>srcTexture [[texture(0)]],
                                                              texture2d<float, access::sample> maskTexture [[texture(1)]])
{

    constexpr sampler defaultSampler;

    float  srcColor = float4(texture.sample(defaultSampler, float2(params.textureCoordinates)))  * float4(1,0,0,40.0/255.0);

    float4 maskColor = float4(texture4.sample(defaultSampler, float2(params.textureCoordinates))) ;

    return srcColor * maskColor

}
```

If I do like this Scenario 2 is missing. Anyway to solve in metal fragment shader. I need three scenarios to be satisfied.

Comment: why you multiple `float4(texture.sample(defaultSampler, float2(params.textureCoordinates)))  * float4(1,0,0,40.0/255.0)` ?

Comment: That is a single color image so to make it red with alpha I am multiplying